# How to implement language toggle in jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-7

I have set up internationalizing in my web page,however, language button toggles by it self after clicking different menu on the menubar. I want to display one language in whole web page unless user changes to a different language.I looked for post related to this but couldn't get one.
Any link, idea or book recommendation would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tag is needed before the beginning of the  and  tag before closing tag in JSF and PrimeFaces.This is needed only in Facelets Template file and not needed in Facelets Template Client file.